# Xdg-open doesn't work in Chromium

Tags: chromium, 20.04, xdg-open

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I've got chromium-browser through apt(same problem persists with snap version).

The problem is that xdg-open doesn't seem to do anything when called from the browser - for example i can't open any magnet or steam links, even though i can open them through

```
xdg-open magnet:
```

or

```
xdg-open steam:
```

The "open xdg-open?" popup is shown, but pressing "open xdg-open" does nothing.

Is there any fix or any alternative to xdg-open i can use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

upd: this seems to be a bug that is not fixed yet, related to snapd.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1776873

Comment: Not sure how it can be related to snapd if installed chromium is from repos and not snap? I just upgraded to Linux Mint 20 (from 19) and now nothing using xdg-open from the browser works, neither in Chrome nor in Firefox.